# Can disabling a control cause a radio buttons value to change?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a **For Each** loop going through the controls in a panel disabling them. When the loop reaches one certain grid control and disables it the **CheckedChanged** event fires for the next control in the loop which is a radio button.

The call stack is as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.OnCheckedChanged(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) + 0x15 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.WnProc(Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WM wm = WM_RADIOBUTTON_NOTIFYVALUECHANGED, int wParam = 0, int lParam = 0) + 0x17 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WM wm = WM_RADIOBUTTON_NOTIFYVALUECHANGED, int wParam = 0, int lParam = 0) + 0x9 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WL.SetEnabled(System.IntPtr hwnThis = 1179753, Microsoft.AGL.Common.BOOL fEnabled = fFalse)    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control._SyncEnabled() + 0x21 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enabled.set(bool value = false) + 0x61 bytes
```

I don't understand how **control.Enabled = False** can cause the OnCheckedChanged event.

Has anyone run into a similar situation and can maybe shed some light on this?

Comment: The plot thickens...I put a simple 'if' statement in the loop to make it skip the grid and now it doesn't fire the CheckedChanged event as before. This pretty much means it is the fact that the DataGrid is getting disabled that is causing this.

Comment: Now i've tried disabling the grid just after the loop and it disables **without** firing the event. So it seems to only be if it is disabled before the radio button is disabled.

Comment: If I disable the grid before the loop, then even stranger, the radio button change event fires when the other grid on the form gets disabled...

Comment: I fixed it by adding **Me.Focus()** before the loop to focus the form. No idea why this fixes it but it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem and solution are explained in more detail here: [Dev center forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/77fbec3b-1f63-42e1-a200-19b261b63794/).
This also explains why setting Me.Focus helps fixing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for finding the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening during the load event? Sometimes RadioButtons fire during form initialization, "By Design" according to Microsoft. If this is the case, you can check in the OnCheckedChanged handler to make sure the form is loaded before you do anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I noticed that it does fire during initialisation when the designer code sets the radio button to the default that was chosen in the designer, but this is quite a bit after.